# SpriteKit SKAction.animateWithTextures: Resize and Restore

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Very easy question but would prefer to have someone tell me if I got it correct.
What are the restore and resize parameters for SKAction.animateWithTextures?

If I have an image that's 500x500, and my animation is 400x400, then resize:true will replace my 500x500 with the 400x400 animation? And restore:true would bring it back to the 500x500 after it's done playing the animation, whereas if that restore was was false it keep make my original 500x500 sprite stay at the smaller 400x400 size?

Thanks I just want to confirm this is the case!

Comment: Partially correct, restore will bring your sprite back to its original state before the animation was run, this includes size and texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417656-animate

@param resize If YES, the sprite is resized to match each new texture.
     If NO, the size of the sprite remains at a constant size.
     @param restore If YES, When the action completes, the sprite’s texture is restored
     to the texture it had before the action completed. (If the
     resize parameter is YES, the sprite is resized to match the
     size of the original texture.
     If NO, when the action completes the sprite’s texture remains
     set to the final texture in the array.

Comment: post the link to documentation

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417656-animate  - although i quoted from inside xcode when your cmd+click the method.